How to solve "Heroku does not support Git client version git/2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)" on Mac?
When trying to deploy an app to heroku using git push heroku main
There was an error
>> git push heroku main
remote: !       Heroku does not support Git client version git/2.39.3 (Apple Git-146).
remote: !       Please upgrade to the latest Git version.
remote: !       For more information, please see https://help.heroku.com/GJ1XRFT5/fatal-error-pushing-to-heroku-on-macos-with-git-2-39-3-apple-git-146
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-brook-74638.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400

I tried fixing the issue with
>> brew update
>> brew upgrade git

And ran git push heroku main again, but the error still persists

The solution is to install git through homebrew with brew install git and overwrite the Apple git preinstalled with the Mac.
The brew update git command probably failed with an error message like
>>> brew update git
brew upgrade git
Error: git not installed
...

Steps:

Run brew install git

Add the following line to your shell configuration file (e.g., .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.):


export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"


Reload your shell configuration

source ~/.zshrc


Run git --version to verify the updated git installed.


In addition to this, try running which -a git to see if there are multiple installations of git present on your machine. If the PATH is not set correctly, the Apple version could be taking precedence. You can also call the homebrew git directly with /usr/local/bin/git to test if that works.

great solution thanks

Heroku won't let us use a version of git that's too old (see heroku docs).
Solution: update git.
If it's installed via homebrew: brew upgrade git
If you installed it another way, just ensure the most up to date version is installed, open a new terminal window, then give git push heroku main another try.
